# I am getting "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable" when I'm trying to iterate over a pandas Dataframe in a Knime python script node

Tags: python, knime

Basically I am tyring to iterate over rows in a pandas data frame.
This data frame was automatically created in Knime through a python script node.

The name of the data frame is "input_table".

The dataframe has three columns: 
Location, URL and Document.

I am gettin this error: TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable, when I am trying to loop over rows.

I already looked for similiar problems, but none of the solutions worked for me. This is the code I am using, since the data frame was created automatically.

```
for index, row in input_table():

   print(row["Document"])
```

Comment: Assuming `input_table` is the name of the dataframe, you're trying to "call" it with the parentheses. Besides that, use df.iterrows() instead for dataframe iteration or you likely won;t get what you expect

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall store the data frame as a csv file and then import it so that you can then normally iterate over pandas dataframe.